# Trying to find the correct xpath

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, xpath

I have made code, see following lines:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
    import time
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

    PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

    driver.get("https://www.flashscore.com/match/jBvNMej6/#match-summary")
    print(driver.title)
    driver.maximize_window() # For maximizing window
    driver.implicitly_wait(10) # gives an implicit wait for 20 seconds

    driver.find_element_by_id('onetrust-reject-all-handler').click()
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,'previewShowMore.showMore').click()

    main = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,'previewLine'[b[text()="Hot stat:"]]/text)
    print(main.text)

    time.sleep(2)
    driver.close()
```

However, I get the following error.

> main = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,'previewLine'[b[text()="Hot stat:"]]/text)
> ^
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

What can I do to avoid this?

thx! : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, in this line

```py
main = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,'previewLine'[b[text()="Hot stat:"]]/text)
```

You have made a great mix :)
Your locator is absolutely invalid.
Also, if you want to print the paragraph text without the "Hot streak" you will need to remove that string from the entire `div` (paragraph) text.
This should do what you are trying to achieve:

```py
main = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div[@class='previewLine' and ./b[text()='Hot streak']]").text
main = main.replace('Hot streak','')
print(main)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not finding any text 'Hot stat:'. You'll have to attach the html code where you found that.

I assume that you want to retrieve the text of a specific previewLine?

```
main = driver.find_element(By.XPATH ,'//div[@class="previewLine"]/b[contains(text(),"Hot streak")]/..')
print(main.text)
```

Comment: That is correct. The line that I wanted to print is the previewLine under the name 'Hot stat:' if I am not mistaking.